# Batch processing renaming

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, rename

I need to duplicate file many times I have a list of product numbers that need to be used as part of the new file name -- so example;

1. original file called `photo.main.jpg`
2. I need to copy the `photo.main.jpg` file many times (I am hoping to put the names to substitute in a file to read)
3. I have product names say 123, 456, 789, 345, 221 in the file and the product name must replace the word "photo" in the file.
4. this scenario i would want 5 new files called `123.main.jpg`, `456.main.jpg`, `789.main.jpg`, `345.main.jpg` and `221.main.jpg`

I am hoping to do in Windows command prompt -- can someone help?

Comment: We shouldn't code for you, we just should help you in your existing code... Where do you have those products names? Will you input them one by one, are in a file, ...?

Comment: Please include code you've tried.

Comment: There is no DOS prompt in modern Windows systems, it's the Windows command prompt...

Answer (score 0):

While this can be done in a cmd shell, PowerShell provides access to
regex processing that can make it very flexible.

The $replpat regex can be anything that provides what the
regex in the Copy-Item command needs. Using $matches is not required.

```
$orgfile = 'photo.main.jpg'
$prodfile = '.\prodlist.txt'
$replpat = '[^\.]*(.*)'

$ismatch = $orgfile -match $replpat
$filebase = $matches[1]

Get-Content -PSPath $prodfile |
    ForEach-Object {
        Copy-Item -Path $orgfile -Destination "$_$filebase" -WhatIf
    }
```